# Why does WordPress (with WooCommerce store) display the Products in my Category page like this?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I click on a Category in my main Shop page, the Products are listed as pictured below, with no thumbnails and only a Read More button, which when clicked, redirects to the same page.

[image]

The WooCommerce side of things seems to be working okay as there are definitely 19 products in that Category. But obviously, site visitors need to be able to see each Product on the Category page, with their accompanying Add to Cart buttons beneath

Is this a Theme-related issue? Or some other WordPress setting which I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily change to a different theme and see if it looks the same.  I'm thinking its a theme issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try Update Permalink, If not Fixed  I highly Recommended Hiring A web developer, If you don't know how WordPress theme works
Actually It Is Theme Related Issue.

For Solving This issue You need to understand about single.php

single.php is a PHP file that triggers when any post requested.
The problem is when you requested a product the single.php is called.